# Excel VBA set printer to shared printer

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a long VBA copying cells from one page to another and trying to print 3 pages to different printers.

The code below does not seem to be changing the default printer and as so all pages are sent to the same printer.

```
 For i = 0 To 15
    curNePrint = Format(i, "00")
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.ActivePrinter = "\\AtanaWin7PC3\DYMO LableWriter 450 on ne" & curNePrint & ":"
    Next i
 Worksheets(le).PrintPreview
```

I have used printPreview to save wasted paper on the printer.

Can anyone help me out here on setting a printer for each page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just tried your code, and I was able to successfully change printers.

I think it is most likely there is a spelling error in your printer name.

Perhaps LableWriter should be LabelWriter?

To determine what the printer name should be, I suggest manually changing your active printer, then do something like a `Debug.Print Application.ActivePrinter` and carefully compare your string result with what you are specifying.

Comment: The OP might also enumerate the printer list using Application.Printers ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/retrieve-a-list-of-installed-printers ) and use `instr()` to identify printers with "DYMO"

Comment: @Yorik It's a good thought, but it looks like your link is for Access rather than Excel.  I can't seem to find a corresponding property for Excel.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Might still be possible via a system call

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i now have this working, do you know how i can change the print from tray?

Comment: Ryan, I don't think you can do that through Excel VBA, but this might be useful:  http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/559625-setting-printing-properties.html